# What does grep -v "grep" mean and do?

Tags: bash, grep

I was wondering what `grep -v "grep"` does and what it means?

Comment: You can `man grep` to read the reference manual page for the command, or for more information on certain commands (inc. grep) you can `info grep`....  ie. your system has documentation which is often very handy.

Comment: `grep -v "grep"` is often used to filter out grep itself while listing processes and that typically involves 3 pipelines, although there's better methods of course like `pgrep` which allow much less "plumbing". See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74185/85039

Comment: That does it. I'm calling my rootkit `grep`.

Comment: Normally used in a non-security-related context such as `ps aux | grep fubar | grep -v grep` where `fubar` is something I am developing, that has stopped responding, and whose id I want to find so I can kill it. Assume there are two of them so `killall` is inappropriate.

Comment: @guiverc You are everything that is wrong with SE. Just answer the damn question and add that as a side note. OMG.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`grep -v "grep"` takes input line by line, and outputs only the lines in which `grep` does not appear. Without `-v`, it would output only the lines in which `grep` *does* appear. See [`man grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/grep.1.html) for details.

As far as the `grep` utility is itself concerned, it's unimportant that the pattern `grep` passed to it as an argument is the same as its name. But in most cases where `grep -v grep` actually appears, this is no coincidence.

**`grep -v grep` (or `grep -v 'grep'` or `grep -v "grep"`) often appears on the right side of a [pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) whose left side is a [`ps`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/ps.1.html) command.** That is likely where you have seen it. For example, I might be looking for running programs whose names, paths, or command-line arguments suggest they're related to Xfce:

```
ek@Io:~$ ps x | grep xfce
 2955 ?        Ssl    0:10 xfce4-power-manager
 2958 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd
31901 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto xfce
```

My `grep` command was shown in the output, but it's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for information on processes that were already running when I examined what was running, not the process that's only running *because* of my effort to examine what is running.

One common way to remove this distraction is to add *another* pipe to `grep -v grep`:

```
ek@Io:~$ ps x | grep xfce | grep -v grep
 2955 ?        Ssl    0:10 xfce4-power-manager
 2958 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd
```

`grep` without `-F` treats its pattern as a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) rather than a [fixed string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242873/grep-for-literal-strings). So another approach is to write a regular expression that matches exactly `xfce` but is written differently. For example:

```
ek@Io:~$ ps x | grep '[x]fce'
 2955 ?        Ssl    0:10 xfce4-power-manager
 2958 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd
```

This works because `[x]` is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches exactly the letter `x`.

---

One shortcoming of those popular methods is that they'll filter out lines that contain `grep` even when they're not the `grep` command you just ran yourself. They might not even be `grep` commands--just commands whose names, paths, or command-line arguments *contain* `grep`. So, as [Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy has pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153513/what-does-grep-v-grep-mean-and-do/1153520#comment1918291_1153513), often neither of those ways (nor any other approach involving piping the output of `ps`) is really ideal and, as [Nic Hartley mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153513/what-does-grep-v-grep-mean-and-do/1153520#comment1918508_1153520), [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/how-can-i-prevent-grep-from-showing-up-in-ps-results) [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375711/more-elegant-ps-aux-grep-v-grep) often use [`pgrep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/pgrep.1.html). For example:

```
ek@Io:~$ pgrep -af xfce
2955 xfce4-power-manager
2958 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/xfconf/xfconfd
```

- `-a` *shows* the full command line. Omit it to show only the process ID number.
- `-f` *searches* in full command line. Omit it to search only the names.

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning `pgrep` for another alternative to `ps | grep`

Answer (score 15):

`grep --help` tells us what `-v` flag does:

```
-v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines
```

You can use `-v` flag to print inverts the match; that is, it matches only those lines that do not contain the given word. For example print all line that do not contain the word bar:

```
$ grep -v bar /path/to/file
```

([read more...](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/))