# How can I pgrep a bash script without detecting the pgrep itself?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script which, once the user run it, checks if another process is running and show it on screen.

Of course, the script is intended for a different purpose, like sending an email once the script ends satisfactorily, or using a different way to send a message to the user.

The main purpose of this script will be to detect zombie processes which kept running for a certain amount of time and inform to the user to take some actions.

I am trying to check if a `php` script is running in the command line, so I have tried using this for checking if the script is running:

### detector.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(pgrep -fl my-php-program.php)
if [ -z "$var" ]
  echo "Not running"
else
  echo "Running!"
fi
```

The script works, and it shows the contents of the running processes, after which I do some other `if...else...fi` validations with the `$var` variable contents to do something.

Nevertheless, if I run the process constantly using:

```
while true; do bash detector.sh; sleep 1; done;
```

The script detects itself and sometimes shows some positive false responses.

I have -unsuccessful- tried this to solve it:

```
var=$(pgrep -fl my-php-program.php | grep -v php)
```

Is it there another way to get this problem solved?

Thanks in advance.

**P.S.: I don't want to solve this problem in PHP. I would appreciate a lot your advice for bash based solutions only.**

Comment: Zombie processes happen because, although the program has exited, there's still a resource (the exit status) that must benefit harvested (`wait`, `waitpid`) by the parent process. Rather than chasing zombies, fix the parent process that starts the eventual zombies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does grep -v "grep" mean and do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153513/what-does-grep-v-grep-mean-and-do) and specially [this given answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1153520/283843)

Comment: @waltinator, thankk you. I will take a look at a solution based on your suggestion. Regards

Comment: @αғsнιη Thank you.I knew that, I was trying to get a solution by excluding the lines which contains the process itself, as I said: unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1):

Since `pgrep` uses an Extended Regular Expression, you could use a regexp that doesn't match itself, e.g.

```
pgrep '[m]y_php_program.php'
```

Read `man pgrep`.